# struts Login app returning back to login page after login form,

Tags: java, authentication, struts

This is my first strut app and I am still not getting it right. It's a simple login app. Where if someone uses admin/visitor credentials, he/she gets to the login page for admin/visitor. Although in my case when I type in the login details, it is coming back to login page again. Please help

1)LoginAction

```
package com.struts.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.struts.form.LoginForm;;

public final class LoginAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;

        // validating login
        if (loginForm.getUname().equals("abc")
                && loginForm.getPwd().equals("abc")) {
            return mapping.findForward("admin");
        } else if (loginForm.getUname().equals("sdf")
                && loginForm.getPwd().equals("sdf")) {
            return mapping.findForward("visitor");
        } else {
            return mapping.findForward("error");
        }

    }
}
```

2)LoginForm

```
package com.struts.form;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionError;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String uname = "";
    private String pwd = "";

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getUname() {

        return uname;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getPwd() {

        return pwd;
    }

    // validating form errors
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        if (uname == null || uname == "") {
            errors.add("uname", new ActionError("error.uname.required"));
        }

        if (pwd == null || pwd == "") {
            errors.add("pwd", new ActionError("error.pwd.required"));
        }

        return errors;

    }
}
```

3)struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="LoginForm" type="com.struts.form.LoginForm"/>
    </form-beans>


    <action-mappings>
        <action input="/login.jsp" type="com.struts.action.LoginAction" name="LoginForm" path="/login" scope="request" validate="true">
            <forward name="admin" path="/admin.jsp"/>
            <forward name="visitor" path="/visitor.jsp"/>
            <forward name="error" path="/error.jsp"/>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

4)web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app >
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</web-app>
```

5) login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#f6f7f8">
        <center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <html:errors/>

        <html:form action="login">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Username:</td>
                    <td><html:text name="LoginForm" property="uname"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr />
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Password:</td>
                    <td><html:password name="LoginForm" property="pwd"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><html:submit value="Login"/></td>
                    <td><html:reset value="Reset"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </html:form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is your first Struts1 app, then make yourself a favor, and decide that it's also your last one. Struts1 is completely obsolete, officially abandoned software. Use a modern MVC framework like Spring MVC.

Comment: If not redirecting properly means, there should be a problem with your `struts-config.xml` file. I hope you can remove the input and path attributes from your action. Let me know if you facing any errors on your java console. Anyway JB Nizet is correct. You may move to srtuts2/spring MVC.

Comment: struts1 is deprecated! use Struts2

Comment: Hmmm... What's **wrong** with [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) (JSF, jQuery)?